# Is there an option in SourceTree that whether or not to delete remote branch when I finish a feature branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

(Sorry for any grammatical mistakes.)

My friend and I did the same steps below by SourceTree:

1. create a feature named "TEST-1234_AAAA" from Develop and switch to it
2. edit a file and make a commit
3. push "TEST-1234_AAAA" to our Git server
4. finish and delete "TEST-1234_AAAA"

Somehow we got different results,
my feature on remote is still alive, but his got deleted.

Here is my output message during feature finishing:

```
sh.exe C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git-flow feature finish TEST-1234_AAAA
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
Switched to branch 'develop'
Updating d004c89..5e0354c
Fast-forward

 readme.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

Deleted branch feature/TEST-1234_AAAA (was 5e0354c).

Summary of actions:
- The feature branch 'feature/TEST-1234_AAAA' was merged into 'develop'
- Feature branch 'feature/TEST-1234_AAAA' has been removed
- You are now on branch 'develop'





Completed successfully.
```

and here is his output message:

```
sh.exe C:\Users\easyuse\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git-flow feature finish TEST-1234_AAAA
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
Switched to branch 'develop'
Updating d004c89..3222d73
Fast-forward

 readme.md | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

To http://[URL of my Git server]/test/wayne_practicing_area.git
 - [deleted]         feature/TEST-1234_AAAA

Deleted branch feature/TEST-1234_AAAA (was 3222d73).

Summary of actions:
- The feature branch 'feature/TEST-1234_AAAA' was merged into 'develop'
- Feature branch 'feature/TEST-1234_AAAA' has been locally deleted; it has been remotely deleted from 'origin'


- You are now on branch 'develop'

Completed successfully.
```

Is there any option or setting can cause the difference?
I would be thankful for any help.